# I cannot use internet and there is no connection after activation of Wireguard

Tags: debian, vpn, port-forwarding, wireguard

I am really noob in this field. I am trying to carry out a server to develop a domotic center with home assistant. The point is that I would like to access remotely to this server because it is in a country house. To do so, I was trying with Wireguard as VPN for a safe conexion. I have installed it using docker compose with the following lines:

```
---
version: "2.1"
services:
  wireguard:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard:latest
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/Madrid
      - SERVERURL=myurl #optional
      - SERVERPORT=51820 #optional
      - PEERS=1 #optional
      - PEERDNS=8.8.8.8 #optional
      - INTERNAL_SUBNET=10.13.13.0 #optional
      - ALLOWEDIPS=0.0.0.0/0 #optional
      - LOG_CONFS=true #optional
volumes:
  - /docker/wireguard/config:/config
  - /lib/modules:/lib/modules #optional
ports:
  - 51820:51820/udp
sysctls:
  - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
restart: unless-stopped
```

When the container is deployed, everything looks nice but at the moment i try to initialize it in a client using the keys or the QR I cannot access to the entire internet and there is not conexion with the server (I have opened the ports as indicated in all the tutorials that i have seen). When I check the register of wireguard client application, I can see that the handshake is not completed and there is not info received (0 bytes received). I am a little bit desperate with all this...

I dont know if it is necessary to know but I have a router that works with a sim card as internet source. In particular it is TL-MR100 model from tp-link.

The .conf file that is used as input for the client app is sthg like this:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.13.2
PrivateKey = ----
ListenPort = 51820
DNS = 10.13.13.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = -----
PresharedKey = -----
Endpoint = myurl.duckdns.org:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

This is the way that I have perform ports forwarding.
[image]

The server OS is debian.
If someone has suffered this same issue, i am here to listen to you. Thank you in advance.

Comment: home and enduser question are offtopic. did you use NAT? you did not show the entire network how it is been setup

Comment: Yes, I am using NAT forwarding. In Virtual Servers section, I have set the external/internal ports with 51820 and using the local IP of the server.

Comment: But based on the Screenshot, its End-User Equipment. is this Question related for your home?